# Add 'clone' route to existing restful controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, controller, routes

I am tryting to add this method to a restful controller (also has working methods for :index, :new, :create, :edit, :update and :destroy):

```
class Admin::ClassSectionsController < ApplicationController
  def clone
    @class_section = ClassSection.find(params[:id])
    @class_section = ClassSection.new(@class_section.attributes)
    render :new
  end
end
```

And the following for the config/routes.rb:

```
Utg::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  root to: "home#index"
  namespace :admin do
    resources :class_sections, except: [:show]
  end

  resources :class_sections, only: [:index, :show]
end
```

How do I add the route for 'admin/class_section/:id/clone'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
namespace :admin do    
  get "class_sections/:id/clone", to: "class_sections#clone", as: "class_sections_clone"
end
```